# PHP-made e-mail not showing up in iPod

Tags: php, email, mime, ipod

Some time ago I've created a PHP-script that sends MIME-encoded e-mails. It works fine, all inclusive with attachments and inline images. Strangely, these e-mails do not show up in the inbox of my iPod Touch (3th generation, iOS 5.1.1), although they show up in Windows Live Mail, GMail and iPads/iPhones of higher generations.
I've compared the source of the original message with the original message forwarded by GMail (as the forwarded message doest get recognised by my iPod). It seems that there is not a single difference in the MIME-structure.

Does someone knows whether there has to be a specific sequence of the To, From, Subject, ...-headers to get it working?
Here is a sample message:

```
[BLADIBLADIBLA]

Date: Wed, 7 Aug 2013 13:02:31 +0000
To: Name <email@domain.com>
Subject: Test 5
X-PHP-Originating-Script: 0:email.php
MIME-Version: 1.0
From: Name <email@domain.com>
Reply-To: Name <email@domain.com>
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=boundMixed
--boundMixed
    Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary=boundRelated

    --boundRelated
        Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=boundAlternative

        --boundAlternative
            Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
            Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7-bit

            [PLAIN TEXT]

        --boundAlternative
            Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
            Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7-bit

            [HTML]

        --boundAlternative--

    --boundRelated
        Content-Type: image/png; name="logo.png"
        Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
        Content-ID: <logo.png@domain.com>

        [INLINE IMAGE DATA]

    --boundRelated--

--boundMixed
    Content-Type: text/plain; name="file.txt"
    Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.txt"
    Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

    [ATTACHMENT DATA]

--boundMixed--
```

For the sake of clarity I replaced the boundary-hashes by human-readable things. Also I intended the different parts to make it more readable; this is not the case for the real data!

Is there possibly a problem with the PHP mail()-function? Or is there a strict rule about the number of linefeeds after boundaries?

Thanks in advance!